# assign sticky position to a sidebar that is in a grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

i'm coding a layout for a website and in that layout i have used a grid template. i want the header and the left sidebar to be sticky, and i have succeded on the header. however, the sidebar will not be sticky. i've been checking out a few solutions on this forum as i have seen a few people have been asking a similar question, but it does not seem to work.

some people have mentioned about putting the "top:0" (i have done this with the header and it works totally) but with the sidebar it does not. i got to the conclusion that it is because the sidebar won't stick before it's 0 and as it's not 0 in the beginning.

another solution i have found is the "position:fixed" this does make the content stick, however the design won't stay at it's original position.

any help would do. thanks in addition.

```
  <body>
    <header>lorem ipsum.
      <span class="navicon">&#9776;</span></header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>entries</li>
        <li>about</li>
        <li>contact</li>
      </ul>
      <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/c82cc09c4f768df4d3f36b2bafd5aea9/tumblr_pwuyez3xOs1v2hjm4o1_640.jpg"> 
    </nav>
    <main>
      <article>
        <h1>date</h1>
        <p>
          <img src="http://elev.stolav.it/CSS/images/dummy1.jpg">
          text
        </p>

      </article>
    </main>
    <footer>fotnoter</footer>
  </body>
```

css:

```
body {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 4fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header"
    "nav main"
    "footer footer";
  padding:10px;
  grid-gap:10px;
}

body>* {
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  grid-area:header;
  font-family:serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:3em;

  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color:white;

  position:sticky;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
}

.navicon {
  margin-top:-10px;
}

nav {
  grid-area:nav;
  border-top:1px solid black;

  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;

  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  justify-content: center;

  position:sticky;
  top:0;

}

li {
  padding:5px;
  padding-right:15px;
  padding-left:15px;
  background-color:#121420;
  color:white;
  border-right:1px solid white;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:0.8em;
}

main {
  grid-area:main;
  padding:0;
  padding-left:10px;
}

article {
  font-family:"Tahoma", sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-align:justify;
}

h1 {
  display:inline;
  font-size:0.8em;
  font-weight:bold;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-top:1px;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}

p {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:12px;
}

img {
  width:100%;
}

footer {
  grid-area:footer;
}
```

i'm not sure what i should cut off in the css code as the overall would show that position:fixed would make the layout going weird. sorry in advance

Answer (score 0):

add `display:block;` (or flex, it depends on your needs), Like this:

```
nav {
  grid-area:nav;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  display:block;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

If it does not work, try wrapping the nav inside a container:

```
<div><nav>...</nav></div>
```

But why don't you put the nav inside the header btw?

Comment: i just tried your solution, and the same thing happens as in the position: fixed

Comment: i tried witht he display:block now and it still doesn't work. the layout is now normal, but sidebar won't stick before it is at the beginning of the page

Comment: it sticks after i added div, but not under the header but over the header